Question about implementations of a memcpy function
This is the code:
void    *ft_memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char   *to;
    unsigned char   *from;

    if (dst == NULL && src == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    if (dst == src)
        return (dst);
    to = (unsigned char *)dst;
    from = (unsigned char *)src;
    while (n--)
        *to++ = *from++ ;
    return (dst);
}

I want to to know if there will be a difference if we use char instead of unsigned char in this function like that:
void    *ft_memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    char    *to;
    char    *from;

    if (dst == NULL && src == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    if (dst == src)
        return (dst);
    to = (char *)dst;
    from = (char *)src;
    while (n--)
        *to++ = *from++ ;
    return (dst);
}

If there is a difference, show me a case where these functions behave differently.

‘I wonder if it will be different …’ Has your testing revealed any differences?

You could compile them both and compare the generated assembly code.

The condition if (dst == NULL && src == NULL) will not detect if only one of them is NULL.

Also, in C you don't need to cast from (or to) void *. It's implicitly convertible to any other pointer type.

@s3dev: Testing is not a feasible technique for determining whether there is a difference because testing can test only a finite number of the infinitely many possible situations in the infinitely many possible conforming C implementations. Testing might find a difference if one exists (but blind testing may be fruitless) but should not be recommended as a technique for determining that no difference exists. A proper engineering technique for that is reading and comprehending the C standard.

@Someprogrammerdude: Re “… void *. It's implicitly convertible to any other pointer type”: No, it is not. It is not automatically converted to or from pointers to function types (and it is not automatically converted from pointers to qualified or atomic types).

Before it was decided that integer types shall all have 2's complement representation (standardized in C23), it was theoretically possible for (signed) char to have more than one representation of the value 0, so it would be legal for the assignment to change the binary representation of the value 0 during assignment. Therefore unsigned char would have been safer since all values have a unique binary representation. In practice, integer types in C implementations have always used, and always shall use 2's complement representations, so you do not need to worry about it.

@IanAbbott  "so it would be legal for the assignment to change the binary representation of the value 0 during assignment." -- I do not think so - yet that obliges a journey into spec land to assert or challenge. Note that with FP, that does not happen (Again, another journey down the rabbit hole.)

@IanAbbott How would it be legal for lets say a signed magnitude system to change the value from 0 to -0 during plain assignment? That sounds completely non-conforming and would break the whole system.

@Lundin AFAIK, in C17, signed zero is only a thing in floating point. It's conceivable that hardware instructions using sign and magnitude or 1's complement signed integer representation could normalize the value when reading it as a signed integer operand.

@IanAbbott I think it can be a thing in oddball implementations like weight/scales applications. I've also used it in some RF filter tuning firmware (the CPU and C still ran 2's complement though). Anyway I don't think it is valid behavior that the program changes the representation of types during assignment. During conversion is another story.

@Lundin It's all irrelevant now anyway since one of the rationales for only allowing 2's complement representation is that there are no extant implementations that do otherwise. But note that the section dealing with assignment operators (and particularly simple assignment) only mentions values, and multiple representations of integer value 0 all have the same value.

@IanAbbott Hmmm, With FP assignment I suspect the spec obliges an assignment of -0.0 to not change the sign.  OTOH when FP non-zero values have redundant encodings (which I think is common in new base 10 FP types), I wonder if the bit pattern must be preserved.

@chux Yes for FP it is desirable to preserve the sign on underflow, but not all implementations support signed zero.

@chux One difference is that FP values are often used to approximate real values so it makes sense to preserve the sign of zero (which may have resulted from arithmetic underflow where the zero is actually approximating some small, non-zero, real value), whereas integer values are exact and there is only one mathematical integer zero.

@chux I guess the implementation does not need to preserve the specific representation of FPDEC values as long as the value remains the same.


... a difference if we use char instead of unsigned char in this function ...


When char is unsigned, no difference.

When char is encoded using 2's compliment, no difference.

When char in encoded using 1s' compliment or sign-magnitude*1 and a trap value exist, then a trap error may occur - thus a difference.
Per comments with @Lundin, this case is not possible as  character types do not cause trap errors - which seems reasonable.  Now with C23 this case is further moot as these small signed integers types only use 2's complement.

When char in encoded using 1s' compliment or sign-magnitude and value read is -0, I think there is still no difference, yet others suggest otherwise.



Other notes

The signature of memcpy() differs.  restrict missing:
void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);

If buffers overlap, code still has well defined behavior, yet not certainly the correct copy functionality.  With memcpy() it is UB.  Without restrict, I'd expect memmove() behavior.

Coding style: I would have expected from to point to const data, yet do not see this as breaking correct functionality.

Casts to/from void * are not needed here.

if (dst == NULL && src == NULL) return (NULL); serves no purpose here as condition is handled in next line if (dst == src) return (dst);.
if (dst == NULL || src == NULL) return (NULL); makes some sense.



Suggested alternative.
#include <string.h>

void* ft_memcpy_alt(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t n) {
  // If still desiring NULL detection ...
  if (dst == NULL || src == NULL) {
    n = 0; // Or perhaps return NULL;
  }
  unsigned char *to = dst;
  const unsigned char *from = src;

  while (n--)
    *to++ = *from++;
  return dst;
}


*1 C23 (released Oct 2024) only allows only 2's complement for signed integer types.
Ref:  C17 6.2.6.1 5
Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined.(*50) Such a representation is called a trap representation.
Ref:  C17 Footnote 50
Thus, an automatic variable can be initialized to a trap representation without causing undefined behavior, but the value of the variable cannot be used until a proper value is stored in it.

C doesn't allow one's complement or sign-magnitude. It used to do so, but even in older versions trap representations are not allowed in character types, see for example C17 6.2.6.1 §5. So this answer is mostly incorrect and misleading.

@Lundin Fair point to assert "C doesn't allow one's complement or sign-magnitude" given C23's release as such non-2's cases deserve a note about the C version.

@Lundin I'll look into the  "older versions trap representations are not allowed in character types".  Since this answer's "When char ... and a trap value exist ..." seems to be the only part really in question, the "answer is mostly incorrect and misleading" appears to overstate.

Maybe, but the question is about whether char/unsigned char/signed char make any difference. Your remarks about using restrict, wrong casts etc are valid but not what the question was about.

Also the part about trap representation and padding bits not being allowed for character types are in C23 too. So that other forms than 2's complement aren't allowed isn't the whole truth. For a theoretical Deathstation 9000 computer it would otherwise be possible to implement a 2's complement character type which apart from the value adds extra padding bits that could be set as trap representations.

@Lundin Hmmm, "... possible to implement a 2's complement character type which apart from the value adds extra padding bits that could be set as trap representations." --> given C23 spec's, "unsigned char shall not have any padding bits." and "signed char shall not have any padding bits", are you suggesting applying this idea to wide character types?

No I'm saying that "only 2 complement allowed" isn't by itself a guarantee that there's no exotic crap going on.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There is no difference.

Your function does not use the values of the de-referenced character types in any way other than assignment.

C allows conversions between all the character types as well as explicit conversions (casts) between pointers to character types. And it also allows us to inspect any object using a pointer to character type (C23 6.3.2.3).

Character types cannot hold trap representations in the current version of C and they never could in the past either. Not even when the language previously allowed exotic signedness implementations (C23 6.2.6.1 §5).

unsigned char and signed char may not contain any padding bits (C23 6.2.6.2).

char will have the same representation as either unsigned char or signed char (C23 6.2.5 §20).



There are other other situations when the character type might matter. Like when calling the ctype.h functions, the int parameter must be either representable as either unsigned char or EOF, or otherwise it invokes undefined behavior. So passing a char/signed char could in theory have a different outcome in those functions than when passing an unsigned char.
But not in case of memcpy-like functions.

Please note that "casting away const" is very bad practice and in some cases undefined behavior. Both of your versions should preserve the const of the src parameter. That is:
const unsigned char *from;
...
from = src; // no cast needed when the pointer type is correct


As noted in comments, if (dst == NULL && src == NULL) is a bug, should be ||. Or better yet do not check for null at all, it gives bad performance, possibly for nothing gained when the caller actually knows what they are doing. It is not the job of a copy function to sanitize user input and so null pointer checks do not belong in library functions, but at the place in the code where the input is validated.

@chux C23 draft N3220 6.2.5 §20: "The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char."
